# Matching pound (#) or empty line comments with regex

Tags: java, regex

As a start, I am using Java, if this influences the regex.

I am trying to match the contents of a line that start with any number of whitespace character but no other, followed by any number of pounds (#), and followed by any characters, then ending with a new line.

Or, a fully empty line with only either whitespace or new line.

I tried finding the first part myself but it doesn't seem to match any of the comments:

`^(?!.+)#+.*$`

It doesn't work even if I include `\r*\n*` on the end

Comment: Using `\s` matches spaces or a newline `^(?:\s*#.*\R|\s+)` https://regex101.com/r/ZJJwyN/1 In Java `String regex = "^(?:\\s*#.*\\R|\\s+)";`

Comment: I tried that but it didn't seem to match my tests https://regexr.com/5s00b

Comment: Could you add the Java related code? The pattern alone might not be enough here. `^` and `$` default to the start/end of a string, unless you've set the [`MULTILINE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE) flag. It would be helpful to see if you've set your flags correctly.

Comment: You have a flag with the `s` modifier where the dot will match a newline, and the selected language is Javascript. What should there tests match? Like this? `^[^\S\r\n]*(?:#.*)?\r?\n` https://regex101.com/r/r5hoKa/1

Comment: **any number of whitespace character but no other ...** - Do you mean there can be no whitespace in the beginning or you mean at least one whitespace?

Comment: See https://regexr.com/5s01i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your [regexr example](https://regexr.com/5s00b) you have selected Javascript and enabled the `s` flag to have to dot match a newline.

If you want to match all lines, you can enable the multiline and global flag instead, and use

```
^[^\S\r\n]*(?:#.*)?\r?\n
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/asKzRb/1)

---

In Java, you might use

```
^\h*(?:#.*)?\R
```

With the doubled escapes backslashes

```
String regex = "^\\h*(?:#.*)?\\R";
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `\h*` Match optional horizontal whitespace chars
- `(?:#.*)?` Optionally match `#` followed by the rest of the line
- `\R` Match any Unicode newline sequence

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Csl2Zy/1)

If you want to match the whole line, and instead of matching a newline you want to assert the end of the string you can use an anchor `$` instead of `\R`

```
^\h*(?:#.*)?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Exfh1H/1)